# Постоянная работа скрипта на сервере

Tags: php

Необходимо, чтобы команда запущенная через консоль работала после закрытия консоли. Т.е. есть RabbitMQ, а именно слушатель очереди. Необходимо его как-то запустить и чтобы он работал постоянно

Comment: Ищите инфу по supervisor

Comment: Я ставил на cron и сам скрипт работал минуту а потом убивался. Не лучшее решение, но мне зашло

Comment: Зависит от ОС и от дистрибутива ОС. В большинстве современных linux можно сделать задачу для systemd и он будет сам при старте системы запускать ваш скрипт и перезапускать его если он вдруг упадет. И конечно еще это зависит от того, какой у вас доступ к машине, на которой запускаете, можно ли править systemd. Но если вы просто запускаете из консоли, то (опять же для linux) запускать его как `nohup php ваш-скрипт.php &` или воспользоваться утилитой screen

Answer (score 4):

если используете systemctl, можно написать сервис

```
# /etc/systemd/system/some-worker.service
[Unit]
Description=Some worker for RabbitMQ
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
RestartSec=2s
Type=simple
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/project/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /path/to/project/worker-script.php
Restart=always
Environment=USER=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Потом стартуете сервис

```bsh
sudo systemctl start /etc/systemd/system/some-worker.service
```

И добавляете в автозагрузку

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/some-worker.service
```